# Set method from webservice to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

I have this function in javascript, which sets all markers and popup info for each marker.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (var i = 0; i < arraylng.length - 1; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(arraylng[i], arraylat[i])
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: " "
    });
    makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker, i);
    markers.push(marker);
}

function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker, i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        alert(arraylat[i]); // working nice 
        alert(arraylng[i]); // working nice 
        infowindow.setContent(arraylng[i] + ", " + arraylat[i]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

                }
```

My question is: How can I add my method from webservice, which return an address from database? Here is code.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetAddressMarker(string lat, string lng) {
    string address = "";
    var plac = GoogleapiBO.getClinicByLatLng(lat, lng);
    address = plac.address + ", " + plac.city;
    address = "'" + address + "'";
    return address;
}
```

All I need, is to get an address from this method (method needs `string lat=arraylat[i] & string lng=arraylng[i]`) and set it into `infowindow.setContent(*here*);`

How can I do this?

Comment: http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494

Comment: i don't get it, is there any simplest method to use webservice in this situation?

Comment: Are you open to using a library for the ajax call to your server side web method or would you need raw Javascript only?

Comment: it can be ajax(but i have no experience with it) or javascript, doesn't matter for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1

Webservice:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetAddressMarker(string lat, string lng) {
    string address = "";
    var plac = GoogleapiBO.getClinicByLatLng(lat, lng);
    address = plac.address + ", " + plac.city;
    address = "'" + address + "'";
    return address;
}
```

Javascript

```
function makeRequest(url, message) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = getResponse;
    httpRequest.open("POST", url, true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpRequest.send(message);
}

function getResponse() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        //convert JSON string into object
        progressInfo(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText)) 
    }
}

function progressInfo(info) {
    //doing something with object info - in your case it should be the string
}
```

to call the method:

```
makeRequest("http://..../webservice/Service.asmx/GetAdressMarker");
```

### Solution #2

setting a javascript variable in the c# code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var address= '<%= _address%>';
</script>
```

code-behind:

```
public partial class Entscheidungen : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string _address;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         bt.Command += new CommandEventHandler(bt_Command);
    }

    void bt_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
         _address = Service.GetAddressMarker(string lat, string lng)
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it may be use full for u

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var webServiceUrl = "../MathService.asmx/GetFullName";
    $("#btnAjax").click(function() {
        var webServiceUrl = "../MathService.asmx/GetFullName";
        var name = $("#txtBoxName").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webServiceUrl,
            data: "{'name':'" + name + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: SuccessCallBack,
            error: FailureCallBack
        });
    });

    function SuccessCallBack(data) {
        alert(data.d);
    }

    function FailureCallBack(data) {
        alert(data.staus + " : " + data.statusText);
    }</script>
```

don't forget to add this attribute to the service:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetAddressMarker(string lat, string lng) {
    string address = "";
    var plac = GoogleapiBO.getClinicByLatLng(lat, lng);
    address = plac.address + ", " + plac.city;
    address = "'" + address + "'";
    return address;
```

}

Comment: I have to downvote you for 1. old jQuery version on new question that does not list jQuery 2. using different case on your script language, 3. most importantly, a syntax error on your callback function 4. Not using full words on your text description and invalid sentence structure. 5. invalid JSON structure of your object and not providing both variables properly.